# GSAP script tags are in order but not working

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

No matter what order the scripts are, no matter what I try, GSAP just does not seem to work. I've tried multiple variations of jQuery and GSAP. Could someone please provide a working example?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
     
    </head>
    <body>

       <div class = "gsap">
        x
       </div>

       <button onclick = "gsap()">run gsap</button>

       <script>
        function gsap() {
            gsap.to(".gsap", {duration: 2, x: 300});
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: View example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817961/10968134

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're loading an old version of GSAP (bad) but trying to use the new syntax of GSAP (good). Load the latest version of GSAP and you'll be good to go. Currently that is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

You can always grab the latest CDN link from [the front page of the GreenSock website](http://greensock.com/) or from any CDN.

To debug errors like this, see if your resources are loading in the network panel of your developer tools.

Additionally using inline event listeners like you're doing in your HTML is not recommend. Instead, use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).